# Why can't I pattern match on the concatenation function (++) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match `**String Newline String**` pattern in a function Split.

```
split::String -> [String]
split[] = []
split (x++'\n':xs) = [x]++split(xs)
```

I'm getting this error:
`Parse error in pattern: x ++ ('\n' : xs)`

What am I doing wrong here?

I know there are other ways of achieving the same result but I'd like to understand what wrong with this pattern. I'm fairly new to Haskell BTW.

Comment: You can only pattern-match on constructors. As you say, `++` is a function.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could explain in detail what you want your function to do. The code you've written does not seem to make very much sense, so I can't tell.

Comment: Great question! Back in '89, I built a language which allowed, in effect, elem x (_ ++ x : _) = True; elem _ _ = False. I miss it.

Comment: @pigworker how about Curry?

Comment: @ErikAllik It's always worth looking for ideas to steal. I'd certainly like to see more fluidity in the input-output modes of the relations we happen to present functionally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One problem (as I understand it) is that `++` is not a constructor of the list data type the way `:` is. You can think of the list data type being defined as

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

Where `:` is a constructor that appends elements to the front of a list. However, `++` is a function (defined in the documentation here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%2B%2B) as

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(++) []     ys = ys
(++) (x:xs) ys = x : xs ++ ys
```

We could define our own data type list like

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)
```

That would mimic the behavior of our familiar list. In fact, you could use `(Cons val)` in a pattern. I believe you could also define a type with a concat constructor like so

```
data CList a = Empty | Cons a (CList a) | Concat (CList a) (CList a)
```

Which you could use to lazily concatenate two lists and defer joining them into one. With such a data type you could pattern match against the `Concat xs ys` input, but you that would only work on the boundary of two lists and not in the middle of one.

Anyway I'm still fairly new to Haskell myself but I hope this is on point.

Comment: thank you. I am a little surprised that not many sources on Haskell clearly define what constitutes a pattern. After reading your answer I looked up pattern matching on functions and found [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching). It clearly mentions that pattern matching works with constructors only. It also uses the (++) function to demonstrate that arbitrary functions cannot be used in patterns.

Comment: For posterity, the formal semantics of pattern matching are defined in the [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17).

Comment: @farhanhubble I berlieve you are either following a *really bad* source, or you failed to properly read it. AFAIK *all* good sources will clearly explain this.

Comment: @farhanhubble: Another way to phrase it is that when you declare a data type, you get both a *value constructor* and a *pattern constructor* (or *value deconstructor*). When you define a function, you only get the value constructor.

Comment: Interesting perspective @Simon Shine. I'm using [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html#deftypes.pattern) as the primary source and although it introduces pattern matching in the context of Algebraic Data Types and constructors, it doesn't elaborate that pattern matching is specific to them.

Comment: @user2407038 I looked up the [link](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17) you provided. It's a good source and I'll keep coming back to it for future reference. Having said that, it might not be very helpful for people not familiar with grammars. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @farhanhubble I think the "Construction and deconstruction" paragraph implies it pretty clearly. How could you "check to see if the value was created using" a function?

Answer (score 4):

Imagine you could. Then matching `"a\nb\nc"` could produce `x = "a", xs = "b\nc"` or `x = "a\nb", xs = "c"` and you'd need some ad hoc rule to decide which to use. Matching against functions is also impossible to reasonably implement in general: you need to find an `x` given `f x`, and there is no way to do this other than trying all possible `x`.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey Romanov. I thought about ambiguity as a cause but expected a more verbose error message like the ones Haskell shows in case of other ambiguities.

Comment: @farhanhubble The logic is basically: because of these issues you can't match on functions, only on constructors; so it wouldn't make sense to try and check if a specific function would give you ambiguity. Instead the grammar rules for patterns are defined to require constructors, so you get a parse error. There could be a better message saying `++` is not a constructor, though.

Comment: Ambiguity isn't even the biggest issue, imo. The biggest issue is probably that matching on functions is equivalent to solving the halting problem, and (equivalently) would require the ability to enumerate an infinite domain in finite time.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Yes, that's what I've said in the third sentence.

Comment: But `++` isn't just any old function. It's the "plugging-in" function for sublist-in-list zippers. Within first-order inductive data structures, candidate spatial decompositions are searchable. There is still the matter of prioritising the search, which programmers must somehow be able to do. One way to do it is to allow ambiguity in patterns only when the function is doing a computation in some MonadPlus. That way, the context decides how to interpret the choices signalled during matching. So I think it's a little premature to decide that this isn't worth thinking about.